# What is the correct syntax for the method returning a struct?

Tags: c++, class, syntax

Can someone help me with how to get this method to work?

```
// At .h file
template<typename T>
class BTree {
public:
    ...
private:
    struct Node {
        T element;
        Node* left, right;
    };
    Node* root;
    Node* getNode();
    ...
};

// At .cpp file
template<typename T>
BTree<T>::BTree() {
   ...
}
// I am stuck on how I would get the getNode() method to work
// I know it's along the lines of...
template<typename T>
BTree::Node* BTree<T>::getNode() {
    ...
}
```

I keep getting compilation errors. Is there a correct way to do it?

Edit: My mistake. I forgot to put `<T>` on the .cpp file

Comment: I'd have loved to help you. But you didn't actually specify the errors. And you didn't present code we can just copy an paste to get *that exact same error*. You can try fixing `BTree::` ---> `BTree<T>::`. Beyond that, create a [mcve].

Comment: In `BTree::Node`, the symbol `BTree` is not a type-name, it's a *template* that can be used to create a type, if you provide the template arguments.

Comment: And wait, CPP file? You should know [templates better be implemented in headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 0):

You should not split template stuff in header/cpp files. That can't work because you need to compile the cpp files with all T known. So simply write header only code here.

The return type "pointer to nested class" needs a `typename` before the declaration, because itself has a template parameter.

```
template<typename T>
class BTree {
public:
private:
    struct Node {
        T element;
        Node* left, right;
    } localNode;   // if you want to have an instance of node in your object
    Node* root;
    Node* getNode();
    BTree();                 // <- you forget the declaration
};  

template<typename T>
BTree<T>::BTree() {
}   
// I am stuck on how I would get the getNode() method to work
// I know it's along the lines of...
template<typename T>
typename BTree<T>::Node* BTree<T>::getNode() { // <- needs typename!
    return new BTree<T>::Node;               // <- simply return the value
    // or 
    return &localNode; // if you have an instance, simply return the address
}
```